# How to display element in proper position in FabricJs despite on it originX and Y?

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I have two almost identical elements except for their top and origin.
I don't understand how to place them on the same left with 2 different origins.
**Here is the expected view:**

[image: Expected view:]

And here is what I get:

[image]

**--> [Here is the link to jsFiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/redlive/201y9s3m/2/) <--**

Note: Their LEFT is same! This is what I'm getting from backend.

Tnx

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('paper');

const red = new fabric.Rect({
    left: 100, 
    top: 50,
    fill: 'red',
    width: 200,
    height: 100,
    originX: 'center',
    originY: 'center'
});

const yellow = new fabric.Rect({
    left: 100, 
    top: 150,
    fill: 'yellow',
    width: 200,
    height: 100,
    originX: 'left',
    originY: 'top'
});

canvas.add(red);
canvas.add(yellow);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="paper" width="400" height="400" style="border:1px solid #ccc"></canvas>
```

Comment: Take a look on [Fabric.js Origin](http://fabricjs.com/test/misc/origin.html)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want? Here  `left` and `top` attrs are same.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('paper');

const red = new fabric.Rect({
    left: 100, 
    top: 150,
    fill: 'red',
    width: 200,
    height: 100,
    originX: 'left',
    originY: 'bottom'
});

const yellow = new fabric.Rect({
    left: 100, 
    top: 150,
    fill: 'yellow',
    width: 200,
    height: 100,
    originX: 'left',
    originY: 'top'
});

canvas.add(red);
canvas.add(yellow);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="paper" width="400" height="400" style="border:1px solid #ccc"></canvas>
```

Comment: No.... Origin should stay CENTER in red object.

originX: 'center', originY: 'center'